# Car class program not displaying updated speed

Tags: python, class

I do not understand what is wrong. Here is my code:

```
class CarClass(object):
    def __init__(self,year_model,make):
        self.__year_model=year_model
        self.__make=make
        self.__speed=0

    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed+=5

    def brake(self):
        self.__speed-=5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed

#create car1 object
car1=CarClass(2013,'TATA')
#updates speed of car
car1.accelerate()
print('The current speeed is:')
car1.get_speed()
car1.accelerate()

car1.accelerate()
print('The current speeed is:')
car1.get_speed()
car1.accelerate()

car1.accelerate()
print('The current speeed is:')
car1.get_speed()
car1.accelerate()

car1.accelerate()
print('The current speeed is:')
car1.get_speed()
car1.accelerate()
```

And here is the output of my code:

```
The current speeed is:
The current speeed is:
The current speeed is:
The current speeed is:
The current speeed is:
The current speeed is:
```

It should be displaying the speed every time it is incremented 5 times, but it isn't displaying any speed. I have been working on this code for a while now, and yet no progress has been made.

Comment: try `print('The current speeed is:'+str(car1.get_speed()))`

Answer (score 1):

when you type `car1.get_speed()` in a python interpreter, you get the returned value all right, but when you are running a program, you need to print it explicitly like this for instance:

```
print('The current speeed is:'+str(car1.get_sp‌​eed()))
```

(otherwise all methods returning something other than `None` will print a lot of nonsense in the console all the time if return code were ignored)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of your code:

```
class CarClass(object):

    def __init__(self, year_model, make):
        self.__year_model = year_model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0

    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed += 5

    def brake(self):
        self.__speed -= 5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed


# create car1 object
car1 = CarClass(2013, 'TATA')

# updates speed of car
for i in range(4):
    car1.accelerate()
    print('The current speeed is: {0}'.format(car1.get_speed()))
    car1.accelerate()
```

As you can see, now it's printing the car's speed after the acceleration, you forgot to print it. Also, try to avoid [copy & paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming) of code blocks, that's an antipattern.